# Why is Module python-magic not available?

Tags: python, pip, s3cmd, python-magic

I am using [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to sync to an S3 bucket from a Mac and I am getting the following warning:

```
WARNING: Module python-magic is not available. Guessing MIME types based on file extensions.
```

But `pip list` shows that `python-magic` is in fact installed.

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
pip          19.3.1 
python-magic 0.4.15 
setuptools   42.0.2 
wheel        0.33.6
```

And `python --version` shows

```
Python 3.7.5
```

And `pip --version` shows

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verify if `import magic` (the code that fails in s3cmd) works by running `python -c 'import magic'` in command line.

If it doesn't, you probably need libmagic installed. Try `brew install libmagic`.

Answer (score 0):

In the s3cmd manual，there is a argument: `--no-mime-magic`. If you use it, there is no warning.

```
./s3cmd --help | grep magic
```

With this command you will find it.